# Turn strict mode ON in innoDB in MYSQL in shared hosting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, cpanel

Is there a way to turn the strict mode of innoDB in MYSQL in shared hosting? Using phpmyadmin or SSH access or something?? Or it must be done by server administrator?

Comment: Server Admin can do that. Use their support system to request those changes if they allow it.

Comment: Can they do it for individual account or it must apply to whole server??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to mysql documentation ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-other-changes-strict-mode.html ) inno db strict mode is a global dynamic setting.

As a dynamic setting you may change it on runtime, but as a global setting you may do it only if your user has the SUPER privilege. Users without SUPER privilege can't manage this setting because its value affects to all clients.

So only server administrators may turn on/off this setting.

Regards.

Comment: Do you know if there is anyway to force mysql to not ignore wrong values and prevent insertion of wrong values?? I know only innodb to do this...is there another way to achieve the same??

Comment: But it's written in the table that it's both, meaning global and session

Comment: Maybe the setting mysql_mode, which may be set per session: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html

Comment: I don't understand your second comment... what do you mean with "written in the table"?

Comment: I've got what you mean... yes it says that can be applied to session and global, but only with SUPER

Comment: There is a table in the first link you posted that explains how each innodb function works. For innodb_strict_mode it says "both" meaning session and global. Do you which sql mode to use to allow the strict mode?? Thanks :)